# Display Image via Imagick

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, images

I would like to display an image which is not accessible for users (.htaccess denies all).

This is my source:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');          

$filePath                       =   JPATH_SITE.'/images/powered_by.png';
$image                          =   new Imagick("{$filePath}[0]"); // [0] means "first page"
$image->setImageFormat('png');
echo $image;            
exit;
```

At this moment this code is located on a sub controller called "attachment.php" and is called by opening a modal view (&task=attachment.showAttachment).

Now I'm getting a lot of strange symbols. But why?

Are there Joomla-On-Board-Tools to include this image?

[image]

I just mentioned that if I'm opening the file in a new tab everything is fine. The problem only occurs if I want to use it in a modal:

```
echo "<li>  <a  href='index.php?option=com_bestia&task=attachment.showAttachment&id=$attachmentid&tmpl=component' 
                class='modal' rel='{size: {x: 980, y: 500}, 
                closable: true}'>
                <i class='icon-search'> </i>
                    $filename
            </a>
        </li>";
```

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "strange symbols"? Maybe add these symbols to your question so we know waht they are ;)

Comment: I updated initial question and posted an image.

Comment: Just mentioned that it works fine opening it in a new tab - but I would like to have it in a modal. Any solution for that?

Comment: What happens if you remove `&tmpl=component` from the URL query in the `href`?

Comment: In this case there is the toolbar appearing (Joomla Admin-Menu) but the error stays the same.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
echo $image->getImageBlob();
```